# file_get_contents() cannot read PHP tags <?php ?>

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using cakePHP and got stuck with this riddle.
Time ago i made function that inserts custom routes dynamically in file using file_get_contents() and string replace functions.

```
$filename = "301routes.php";
$path = SERVER_PUBLIC_PATH . 'app' . DS . 'config';
$add_data = "Router::connect('".$old."', array('controller'=>'index_router', 'action'=>'redirect_301','".$new."'));\n";
$file_data = file_get_contents($path . DS . $filename);
$file_data = str_replace("<?php\n","<?php\n".$add_data,$file_data);
file_put_contents($path . DS . $filename, $file_data);
```

this worked, but now i tried to put exactly the same function in other project and its working only when there is no PHP tag. Problem is with file_get_contents() function becouse it reads file well when content is:

```
// routes here
Router::connect('/articles/category/en/test', array('controller'=>'index_router', 'action'=>'redirect_301','/articles/category/en/test-old'));
```

but when i change beginning like this

```
<?php
Router::connect('/articles/category/en/test', array('controller'=>'index_router', 'action'=>'redirect_301','/articles/category/en/test-old'));
?>
```

file_get_contents() returns only part of file:

```
string(154) "'index_router', 'action'=>'redirect_301','/articles/category/en/test-old')); ?>"
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Ttake a look at the unix command `sed`. It will save you some time for things like that.

Comment: `file_get_contents()` won't strip part of the file. However, your function will include the `<?php` and `?>` tags in your array. Are you sure this isn't just a display problem?

Comment: Yes, this was ony a display problem. I didn't realize that at the beggining

Answer (score 0):

To run php codes and assign to $file_data variable,

```
ob_start();
$file_data = file_get_contents($path . DS . $filename);
ob_end_flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try: Create new file 301routes.php in config directory then read write permission of file.
$filename = "301routes.php";
$path =  __DIR__;
$add_data = "Router::connect('".$old."', array('controller'=>'index_router', 'action'=>'redirect_301','".$new."'));\n";
$file_data = file_get_contents($path . DS . $filename);
$file_data = str_replace("<?php\n","<?php\n".$add_data,$file_data);
file_put_contents($path . DS . $filename, $file_data);
```